# Java runtine.exec: doesn't change path

Tags: java, console, runtime

**java**:

```
public static void startCmd(String path)
{
  Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
  Process pr = rt.exec(path);
  BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream(), "cp852")); 
  String line = null;

  // redirection output to console
  while((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
  }
  System.out.println("Error code: " + pr.waitFor());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  startCmd("c:\\run.bat");
}
```

**run.bat**:

```
cd c:\cmd\
application.exe
```

**output in console**:

```
D:\WORKSPACE\TEST>cd c:\cmd\ 
D:\WORKSPACE\TEST>application.exe // path should be changed from D:\WORKSPACE\TEST> to c:\cmd>
Error code: 0
```

Why the `cd c:\cmd\` command isn't passed to java console application???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under `DOS`, when changing the path to another drive it is necessary to use the drive letter before the directory can be set. This is due to the fact that each drive has its own working directory. You need to add `C:` to the batch file:

```
C:
cd c:\cmd\
application.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cd c:\cmd\
c:
application.exe
```

Try this.